# Send file to server in grails 3.0.0.1

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I'm doing some test with grails 3.0.0.M1 and I have a form that sends a file to server using :

In view:

```
<g:uploadForm controller="file" action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</g:uploadForm>
```

and In the controller I have:

```
def file() {
    def f = request.getFile("file")
    //....some code  
}
```

With f I have a NullPointerException that is to say the server don't receive the file from the view.
How how I can fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the actual stack trace so it includes the line number as well as the remaining portions of your Controller code as well? Without more details it's going to be difficult for someone to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues in Grails 3.0.0 M1 regarding file uploads, please try 3.0.0 RC2

Comment: Thaks for your response!